# Listing links in designated worksheet vba

Tags: vba, excel

I amended the below so the links would go into a sheet of my choosing, but I get errors, I am keen to know is there a way of setting the ws of my choosing. I looked on the net and could not find a solution.

```
Sub ListLinks()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
If Not IsEmpty(wb.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)) Then
    wb.Sheets.Add  '  Amended this with my chosen sheet I want the links to go and I get errors after, declaring my variables, i.e ws as worksheet and the range
    xIndex = 1
    For Each link In wb.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
        Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(xIndex, 1).Value = link
        xIndex = xIndex + 1
    Next link
End If
End Sub
```

I have a workbook, that has several worksheets that have two external links to two different workbooks.

I am unable to use left or right function to extract the path filename from a VLOOKUP FORMULA of a cell to a cell of my choosing, let's take the example of one link, let's say that I wanted to print the formula as text into cell B1 and then say C1 would have the path of the most updated file that I would want to change it to. Using VBA to change the file. Once this has updated the link, both B1 and C1 should = the same file and path location.

If I could do this than I would try to see if I could apply it to the second link.

Is there a way of printing the formula of a cell as text and then using left, middle or right to extract path and file location.

I thought about the above vba code but it adds a new sheet, I am unable to put the links into the sheet of my choosing. I get an error. I would be keen to use as less code as possible. I am a newbie in VBA, thoughts, and help would be appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get, at what line?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to write to an existing sheet then instead of adding a sheet, you just need to specify the sheet on the writing line. So first remove the line `wb.Sheets.Add`. Then modify the write line - change `ActiveSheet` to `Sheets("your sheet name")`. In this example I've specified an existing sheet named "sandwich":

```
Sub ListLinks()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    If Not IsEmpty(wb.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)) Then
        xIndex = 1
        For Each link In wb.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
            Application.Sheets("sandwich").Cells(xIndex, 1).Value = link
            xIndex = xIndex + 1
        Next link
    End If
End Sub
```

Additional:
If you wish to get the path from the formula/link, without VBA you may be able to use a formula like this if you are using Excel 2013 or later (in this example, your link is in cell A1):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(FORMULATEXT(A1),FIND("'",FORMULATEXT(A1),1)+1,(FIND("]",FORMULATEXT(A1),1)-FIND("'",FORMULATEXT(A1),1)-1)),"''","'"),"[","")
```

Comment: Ace, glad it helped! :-) Please 'accept' the answer if you don't mind.